# Ajax запрос отрабатывает 1 раз, 2й и последующие не обрабатываются

Tags: php, ajax

Доброго. И грешник я, т.к. с вопросом в воскресенье!

Вообщем 1 единственная страница PHP + Jquery. Нажимаем на текст - идет POST запрос, страница перезагружает часть. Второй и последующие разы не проходят. Для проверки ввел переменную в сессию, оказалось что и с сессией работа не идет. Опять же на хостинге такая же штука.

В чем дело? Может кто подсказать?

```
<?
session_start();

//страница, при передаче POST запроса Ajax'ом
if($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"]=="XMLHttpRequest"){

    //просто меняем переменную туда-сюда
    if(isset($_SESSION['catalog_tray']['all']) AND $_SESSION['catalog_tray']['all']=='yes'){
        $_SESSION['catalog_tray']['all']=='no';
    }else{
        $_SESSION['catalog_tray']['all']=='yes';
    }

    //блок для обновления
    echo '
        <div id="super_id_101" class=" buttonUpload" value="101">101</div>
        <div id="super_id_115" class=" buttonUpload" value="115">115</div>
    ';
    echo time();
    echo '<pre>';print_r($_SESSION['catalog_tray']);echo '</pre>';
}

//страница, НЕ при передаче POST запроса Ajax'ом
if($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"]!="XMLHttpRequest"){
    ?>
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <style>
                    body,table,tr,td,div,select,input,a{ font-family: calibri;}
                    a{ text-decoration:none;}
                </style>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery2.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $(".buttonUpload").click(function(){
                        $.ajax({
                            url:"index.php",
                            type:"POST",
                            cache:true,
                            data: "id="+$(this).attr("value"),    
                            success: function(html){    
                                $("#category_tray_one").html(html);
                            }

                        })
                    });
                });
                </script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="category_tray_one" class="">
                    <div id="super_id_101" class=" buttonUpload" value="101">101</div>
                    <div id="super_id_115" class=" buttonUpload" value="115">115</div>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    <?
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все потому что к динамически добавленным элементам ранее объявленная click функция не привязана. Один из вариантов решения проблемы

```
<?
// все ошибочки показываем
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
session_start();

//страница, при передаче POST запроса Ajax'ом
if ($_POST){
    //блок для обновления
    echo '<div id="super_id_110" class="buttonUpload" value="110">110</div>
        <div id="super_id_120" class="buttonUpload" value="120">120</div>';
    echo time();
}

//страница, НЕ при передаче POST запроса Ajax'ом
if(!$_POST){
    ?>
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <style>
                    body,table,tr,td,div,select,input,a{ font-family: calibri;}
                    a{ text-decoration:none;}
                </style>
                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        function update(){
                            $(".buttonUpload").click(function(){
                                $.ajax({
                                    url:"index.php",
                                    type:"POST",
                                    cache:true,
                                    data: "id="+$(this).attr("value"),
                                    success: function(html){
                                        $("#category_tray_one").html(html);
                                        update();
                                    }
                                })
                            });
                        }
                        update();
                    });
                </script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="category_tray_one" class="">
                    <div id="super_id_101" class="buttonUpload" value="101">101</div>
                    <div id="super_id_115" class="buttonUpload" value="115">115</div>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    <?
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

в jquery 1.7+ можно сделать по другому

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#element').on('click', function(){ //или $(document).on('click', '#element', function(){
//ваш код
});
});
</script>
```

и все будет прекрасно работать

Comment: Для более ранних версий есть функция live.